# Cassandra: How to query local Table from local node in Java?

Tags: java, cassandra, local, cqlsh

I have a three-node cluster with replicationfactor 2 and I want to receive the table `local` from keyspace '`system`'.
That means I want to acess local data of a Cassandra node.
Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by local data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can query the `system.local` table from within Java just like any other.

```
    session = cluster.connect();
    ResultSet results = getSession()
        .execute("SELECT key,broadcast_address,cql_version FROM system.local");

    for (Row row : results) {
        System.out.println(row.getString("key") + " "
            + row.getInet("broadcast_address") + " "
            + row.getString("cql_version"));
    }

local 127.0.0.1 3.4.4
```